# How to convert national poverty into an international comparable measure?

Tags: macroeconomics, statistics, international-economics, poverty

I want to compare the poverty of a subpopulation of my country (indigenous people) to other countries' poverty. To do that, I have the per capita income of each individual of my dataset expressed in 2022 dollars. In order to make comparisons with the World Bank poverty measures, I think that I have to transform this variable so that it reflects 2011 PPP dollars and then just use the 1.90 poverty line to calculate the national poverty.

For my country, the PPP is 0.535 (related to 1 US dollar). Should I multiplicate my variable by this number? Also, how do I express it in real terms (that is, in 2011 dollars)?